# Removing files with a double quote in their name

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove files within a directory. Some of the files have double-quotes around their name while others do not. An example of these files would be:
`"DDD344".csv`
`D2DW.csv`
Both these files are located in sub-directories within the directory `YM`.

To `find` such files and remove them, I invoke `find` like so:
`find YM -name "*.csv" -print | xargs rm`

The above command results in a lot of `No such file or directory` errors.
I tried using `sed` in the following way:

`find yum/yum_hyd -name "\"*\".csv" | sed 's/"/\"/g' | xargs rm`
but to no avail. How do I remove the files?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding the answer. It is also off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
find yum/yum_hyd -name "\"*\".csv" |sed 's/"/\\"/g'|xargs rm
```

explanation:

you want to replace `"` with `\"`. but if you write `\"` directly, sed considers it as plain `"`, you have to escape the backslash. so `\\"` works.

Comment: an explanation of the double `\\` in the sed expression would be nice.

Comment: In your example the sed command was essentially replacing a " with a "
In this example the sed operation is replacing a " with a \"

Comment: Because broken answers that hide a few symptoms of doing it wrong are worse than no answer at all. This could easily blow up if given the wrong filenames.

Comment: @ormaaj, the filenames are not given by you, they are coded by OP. see the question. ... with your logic, taking your answer as example, if the "wrong" filename is given, e.g. `"*".css`, all css files are gonna removed.. but who can control that?

Comment: It would be impossible for any filename to influence the results of my answer, but in any event, the question doesn't specify that *only* files that follow that form are being dealt with. Even if it did, it doesn't matter. There's no point in writing fragile code that relies upon filenames being sane when it's so easy to just follow good practice always.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using `xargs`. `xargs` is a horribly broken program that should never be used for anything except in conjunction with the nonstandard `-0` option. Even so, I can't think of any advantages to doing that in this case. You should just execute rm directly from find.

```
find . -type f -name '"*".csv' -exec rm -f -- {} +
```

Will work. If you have GNU find, you may also use `-delete`.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware of this option until recently but you can list the inode of the file in the following way:

> $ ls –il

In the output you will see that the first column contains the inode value.  You can then use that value to `find -inum` the offending files and remove them.
Output

2616366 -rw-r--r-- 1 etc etc

```
$ find . -inum 2616366 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

This will remove the file with that specific inum.

As a test you can run the following to locate your files.

```
ls -il \"* | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I {} find -inum {}
```

Replace the final portion of this command (the "find -inum {}") with the "rm" command once you are satisfied.

This is also similar to the question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/143125/remove-a-file-on-linux-using-the-inode-number)